# как на winapi отслеживать создание файлов чужими процессами?

Tags: winapi, файловая-система

На ноутбуке осталось мало памяти, и она постоянно убывает (иногда возвращается назад). Как моя программа (используя Win API) может следить за созданием новых файлов? Т.е. сообщать в какой папке и какая программа (процесс) создал новый файл, а также размер этого файла.

Comment: Если у вас задача не программирования, а "один раз найти кто создаёт файл" то используйте **FileMon** или другую подобную утилиту от sysinternals.

Comment: Спасибо за программу, но как раз интересно запустить свою, хочется применить winapi на практике.

Answer (score 3):

`FindFirstChangeNotification()` и иже с ней. Можете зарегистрировать нотификацию на изменение размера файлов на диске.

Comment: Прошу меня простить за наглость, но не могли бы вы добавить ссылки на мануалы или что-то подобное, в которых ( по вашему мнению) лучше всего описан данный функционал и как с ним работать ?

Comment: @alexoander начните с чтения описания указанной функции в MSDN. Где-то там и пример будет, точно говорю.

Comment: Спасибо, начал изучать эту команду, а также change journals. Хочется понять, чем эти методы отличаются.

Answer (score 2):

То, что вы хотите, называется hook.
Пример создания хука как раз на функцию создания файла можете посмотреть здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066857/hook-createfilew
В двух словах это не опишешь.

Comment: Не нужен хук, есть готовый механизм нотификации.

Comment: Значит, я отстал от жизни

Comment: Нужные API еще в XP появились...